# Set Entity State to Modified for entities with different reference

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, automapper

I am working on WPF Application using MVVM pattern, also I use EF code first for database entities. and because of MVVM I use AutoMapper to map objects from Database "Models" to "ViewModels".

When I update an entity I have to map it back from view model to model and pass it to the update method

```
public void Update(TEntity entity)
{   
    TEntity databaseEntity = Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(entity.Id);
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = Context.Entry(databaseEntity);
    dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);  
    dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

The problem here I have to Get the entity each time I want to update it, and if I have many objects to update it will cause performance issue. I tried to use this following code but it didn't work because the auto mapper create new instance of the entity different than the one attached with EF dbConext.

```
public void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    DbEntityEntry<TEntity> dbEntityEntry = Context.Entry(entity);
    dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

I tried to handle this by overriding Equals and GetHashCode methods but it also didn't work.

Is there any way to handle update entity without getting it form the database?

Thank you.

Comment: You probably are missing something, it should work properly. For example, if you are using the same instance of context for loading data and saving data, you will face with an exception. Take a look at [Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're manually tracking changes you should not retain a reference to the same dbcontext. Read your data inside a Using statement which news up and disposes the dbcontext.
When you write the data back new up an entity, set the properties to those from your viewmodel, set it's state to modified and savechanges. 
Again, open and close your dbcontext round this.
There is then no need to go find the entity you read.

Here's a trivial example in case that explanation was unclear.
This does not represent a best practice enterprise solution - I would expect at least  a generic updateentityasync method.
We're updating a Person in a People table.

```
    public async Task<bool> UpdatePersonAsync(Person person)
    {
        int numUpdated = 0;
        using (var db = new AndyPeopleContext())
        {
            db.People.Add(person);
            db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
            numUpdated = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return numUpdated == 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, this would work with me fine but the problem with this solution is the repository pattern used in the app, if I go with this solution unit of work will work probably I guess?